# How locking actually works

Tags: c, multithreading, locking

I got one question a very simple one.
while implementing a simple locking mechanism using global variable.I can't find out how to prevent the access of global variable from 2 processes/thread.

### My algorithm (take 2 process)

- Process p1 check if variable g is set then do not modify the code.
- If not set then set it then modify code.
- Same for process 2 .

while executing I got fair result but is it correct.
My doubt in some architecture if 2 instructions are not atomic then how to avoid accessing the global variable at a time.

please give me some basic idea.

Comment: Are you asking about processes or threads ? Processes does not share global variables. Threads do. The next important thing is how you check. A simple `if` statement might executed in an atomic fashion, more likely it will not, and you might be subject to compiler or processor reordering.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using mutexes?

Comment: ok, here my point is something accessible by both process (IPC) or something like that.Doing to know the things. nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Use atomic methods to manipulate the global variable.

Atomic operations are 'built-in' to **[gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)**.  While they are not generally 'portable', most compilers offer atomic operations.

For GCC, you might implement something like this:

```
if(__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&g, g, g+1))
   /* Changed by you. */;
else
   /* Another process changed it before you could. Perhaps try again. */
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't actually do this. There are just too many ways to get this wrong and writing low-level synchronization code, other than for experimental purposes, should be reserved for experts. More than once, someone has shown me their "super-optimized synchronization primitive" and I've pointed out mistake after mistake that they've made. You need deep platform-specific knowledge about, for example, how your code creates cache-coherency traffic and how it's affected by hyper-threading to get it right.

Comment: C11 supports _atomics_ and operations on _atomics_, e.g. `static _Atomic int answer = 0; int expected = 42; atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&answer, &expected, 6 * 9);`

Comment: @nosid If you really understand C++11 atomics, you can avoid locks in some cases without needing deep platform-specific knowledge. It's still, unfortunately, pretty easy to do things badly and wind up with a solution that's vastly inferior to just using a mutex.

Comment: I like the comments,Thank you. but what needs to be done .is there any way or what to do..As the link shows it only applicable for intel if so what to be done for ARM architecture.